# using local dns to allow domain based transparent proxy

Tags: linux, dns, proxy

I am from iran and some websites are blocked for iranian ips (like nvidia and intel and so on).
there is this website that advertise that I can access those domains buy just changing my dns to theirs.
so I tried and I saw this:

```
me@laptop ~> drill devtalk.nvidia.com @94.232.174.194
devtalk.nvidia.com.     300     IN      CNAME   uk4.shecan.ir.
uk4.shecan.ir.  134     IN      A       5.226.141.227
```

the shecan.ir the the the site that advertise that.

now legality of what their doign aside how this works?
do they just redirect traffic to those sites from a non-iranian ip (uk4.shecan.ir    5.226.141.227) so in effect it is just a proxy.
but they dont proxy all the domains just the blocked one.

I am asking this because I wanted to do this for my self on my router but whatever https transparent proxy that I tried cant differentiate between domains. Do they do this with ips?
so when I use their dns service they give me a dns answer and I connect to that I send my request to that but how do they diff between the domains?
do they use different IPs for all those blocked domains?
is that feasible?

can I do this on my own router?

basically I am trying to test this:
use my dnsmasq to give local IP for the blocked sites(blocked by my isp)
then use iptable on that lan machine to transparently proxy all the traffic via tor.
but my issue is does this work with me giving local destination for blocked domains?

I am doing all this so that I don't have to proxy all my traffic and just proxy the needed domains.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that on your own router. The `dnsmasq` running on your router uses the `/etc/hosts` file on the router, so you have to edit this file, enter the domains you want to re-route, and give them (different) IP addresses from the private range.

Then you need the `iptables` rules to DNAT them to their real address, and sent them out via the tor interface.

This will be a bit of a hassle to manage when IP addresses for domains change, because you'll have to update your configuration.

An alternative would be to use a different network namespace on your PC, start two browsers (one in the main namespace, one in the new namespace), wire up the namespace to use tor as a gateway, and in this way differentiate between traffic you want proxied, and traffic you can do directly.

Comment: what? I specifically dont want to use the real(actual) ip of the sites. I am trying to do transparent proxy only for some domains on router level and do that without using their actual ip becuase many sites share ips (like on cloudflare). I am aware about explisit proxy and transparent proxy for all connections (80 and 443)

Comment: Re-routing stuff on the domain level doesn't work, sorry. At least not without a customized DNS server, and I don't know any existing software for that. If all you care about is http/https, you can use an http/https proxy, that can work on the domain level.

Comment: then how those guys in my example do it?

Comment: As I wrote: with a customized DNS server. After all, you just "change your DNS to theirs", as you wrote in your question. And yes, you can write your own, too. Though that's probably not the variant with the least effort (unless someone has already written something like it, and made it open-source).

Comment: so just using dnsmasq to assign ip (local) to them is not enought?

Comment: You also need to redirect the local IP to the real IP (via Tor). And the real IP can change. Or like I wrote: "Then you need the `iptables` rules to DNAT them to their real address, and sent them out via the tor interface. This will be a bit of a hassle to manage when IP addresses for domains change, because you'll have to update your configuration."